# How to insert a row into SQL Server 2005 using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS 2008 and SQL Server 2005. I am using below code to insert a row to a table.

Table is `TestTable`, and it has a single column `Name` (`varchar(50)`).

I am new to C# coding.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "insert into TestTable(Name) values (vinayak)";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VINAYAK-PC;Initial Catalog=TestTable;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "test"); // assign value to parameter 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the parameter in the SQL statement.

Change vinayak to @Name.

Answer (score 0):

In table "TestTable" if you have only one column "Name" and you want to insert value "vinayak" in that then include vinayak in single quotes and you do not need to execute following statement -:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "test");
```

if you want to use parameter in your sql command then make sure u prefix "@" before "name" in your sql command.

see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)